# IC -“derivation tree"

Tags: articles, pronouns

Could you please check my “derivation tree"?

I'm not sure about position of article (the) and pronoun(her). Is it right to put them like this?

Maybe other mistakes?
[image]

Comment: It looks fine, but I'm not sure you're supposed to post questions like this here since you're basically asking other people to do a homework assignment.

Comment: @Peter It appears that the OP has specifically stated a part of the sentences that troubles her, which is what we require... seems fine to me.

Comment: I like this format for sentence diagramming.  Do you have a software tool that makes it easy to draw these diagrams?

Comment: I've done it with Microsoft Word:)

Answer (score 1):

**The pearl ear-rings** and **her rosy ears** are the two **noun phrases**.

Looks fine.